# Is it possble to install .pkg.dmg in Ubuntu

Tags: 11.04

I have a mac disc image of the software for my Expresso USB modem in Ghana. Just as the title says can i convert and install the software for Ubuntu?

Comment: why does ubuntu not provide this kind of package format which can be installed easily?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this software is for a Mac OS system only, and will not be usable in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of the modem are you using? The newest one has software packages for all the different  OSs. Again you can check for your required package from http://ztemt.com/ennewzte/service/default.action.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to install dmg2img
then please check here

http://iremedy.net/blog/2010/11/how-to-mount-a-dmg-file-in-ubuntu-linux/

or here:

http://www.ehow.com/how_6674841_install-dmg-file-ubuntu.html

I had the same question about .dmg files and found those!
Good Luck